# How to make random.shuffle truly random?

Tags: python, random, shuffle

So I have this list:

```
words = ["Games","Development","Keyboard","Speed","Typer","Anything","Alpha","Zealous","Accurate","Basics","Shortcut","Purpose","Window","Counter","Fortress","Modification","Computer","Science","History","Football","Basketball","Solid","Phantom","Battlefield","Advanced","Warfare","Download","Upload","Antidisestablishmentarianism","Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious","Discombobulation","Liberated","Assassin","Brotherhood","Revelation","Unity","Syndicate","Victory"]
```

And I have this which shuffles it and displays it on a label:

```
entry.delete(0, tkinter.END)
random.shuffle(words)
label.config(text=str(words[1]))
timeLabel.config(text="Time: " + str(time_score)+ "s")
```

I'd like to know how to make this shuffle truly random because it feels like I'm getting the same word over and over again despite there being a lot in the list. 
Maybe there is a way to remove a value from the list once it's been taken from it so it can't be shown again?

Comment: What should happen after _every_ word is removed from the list so it can't be shown again? Also, a word appearing twice in a row means it _is_ random. If you could make a prediction about the entry's future state based on its current state (for example, "the entry shows 'Games' right now, so it won't next time"), then that would be less random.

Comment: Not every word will be removed as this block of code only runs 12 times and there's more than 12 words in the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
import random
random_word = random.choice(words)
```

to choose random word from your array. Then you can do:

```
words.remove(random_word)
```

to remove this randomly selected word from array to avoid getting it again if you want to get next random word.

**Edit - answer to the comment**

When I run this code below I'm getting different word every time. Is this the logic you are looking for?

```
words = ["Games","Development","Keyboard","Speed","Typer","Anything","Alpha","Zealous","Accurate","Basics","Shortcut","Purpose","Window","Counter","Fortress","Modification","Computer","Science","History","Football","Basketball","Solid","Phantom","Battlefield","Advanced","Warfare","Download","Upload","Antidisestablishmentarianism","Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious","Discombobulation","Liberated","Assassin","Brotherhood","Revelation","Unity","Syndicate","Victory"]

import random
while words:
    random_word = random.choice(words)
    print(random_word)
    words.remove(random_word)
```

Comment: I put it like this: `random_word = random.choice(words)` then `random.shuffle(random_word)` then `words.remove(random_word)` and it throws an error saying `object 'str'  does not support item assignment` Did I put it the wrong way round?

Comment: There's no need for `random.shuffle(random_word)`

Comment: But after I remove that, the words won't shuffle

Comment: Do you need to shuffle every time or just choose different random value every time?

Comment: I used the wrong words in my reply, I meant to say that the word doesn't change.

Comment: You mean that `random_word` doesn't change? To change you need to run `random_word = random.choice(words)` again. Shuffling is not changing the value of `random_word` variable.

Comment: All of this code is in a while loop but the word won't change.

Comment: @Inkblot Are you still doing `label.config(text=str(words[1]))`? You need to do `label.config(text=random_word)`.

Comment: Wait I forgot to change `label.config(text=str(words[1]))` which displays it on a label to `label.config(text=str(random_word[1]))` but now it only displays letters?

Comment: Remove `[1]` because `random_word` is a string and you treat it like an array otherwise :)

Comment: Thank you @grael and Kevin for your help, it works fine now!

Answer (score 4):

A variation @grael's solution is to shuffle, and then use `list.pop` to remove items.  There's no need to shuffle your list more than once.

```
In [54]: words = ['foo','bar','baz','quux','bizby','squiggle']

In [55]: random.shuffle(words)

In [56]: while words: print(words.pop())
bizby
bar
foo
baz
squiggle
quux
```